How to configure CheckMarx One in a JenkinsFile
Here is a snippet of a JenkinsFile which does Checkmarx SAST scans
        stage('checkmarx') {
            steps {
                    step([
                        $class: 'CxScanBuilder',
                        comment: '',
                        configAsCode: true,
                        customFields: '',
                        excludeFolders: '',
                        exclusionsSetting: 'job',
                        failBuildOnNewResults: false,
                        failBuildOnNewSeverity: 'HIGH',
                        filterPattern: '''**/*.groovy''',
                        fullScanCycle: 10,
                        generatePdfReport: true,
                        groupId: '438',
                        highThreshold: 0,
                        preset: '100087',
                        projectName: DataIngestionforIndustryCloudSolutionswithSAPS4HANA,
                        sastEnabled: true,
                        sourceEncoding: '9',
                        vulnerabilityThresholdEnabled: true,
                        vulnerabilityThresholdResult: 'FAILURE',
                        waitForResultsEnabled: true
                    ])
            }
        }

Can this snippet be replaced to do a Scan using CheckMarxOne?
I have tried using CheckMarx One using a Freestyle project instead of a pipeline project. But my existing Jenkinsfile has a lot of code that would not be present in a Freestyle project.
Is there a way we can rewrite this code in a Freestyle project?
